# Executing batch file in entire git repo

Tags: git, batch-file

I have created a batch file in the top directory of my git repo and I was wondering if there was an easy way to make it so this batch script was executable in every directory of that repo.

I know I could always add it to my path environment variable, but i would like to have this functionality working for other people who clone the repo without having to change their env vars.

I am not sure if this is even possible but thought I would ask just in case.

Comment: Don't try to change other people's execution environment like that, it's called "code injection" when abused and it's got a bad track record.

Comment: That's exactly what the point of this question is. I'm trying to avoid altering people's environment.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.

I have a similar repo, with  a README clearly explaining what script the user has to run in order to modify the environment variables.
And even then, those variables are only modified in the local shell session. Once that session ends, the user/system environment variables are unchanged.